# Problem setting up SMB share on Lubuntu 16.10

Tags: lubuntu, sharing, smb

I'm running Lubuntu 16.10 on a machine which will mainly act as a file server. I want to create some SMB shares, which I was led to believe would be simple (!)....so having not found anything in the GUI I launched shares-admin from the command line. I got:

```
Sharing services are not installed
- Install Unix networks support (NFS)
- Install Windows networks support (SMB)

I clicked the option to install both, then got:
Could not install package
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PackageKit was not provided by any service files
```

Any ideas?

I REALLY, REALLY want to use Linux for this server, but every time I come back to it I find myself losing hours trying to do things that are 2 minute jobs on Windows :0(

Answer (score 0):

Using `Synaptic`, install `system-config-samba` for a GUI way to create shares.

Or, in `Terminal`, type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
```

Then, in your Unity dash, find the `Samba` application, and have fun!